# Query needed to check if an email already exist in a DB(Java Persistence API)

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, jpql

I try to figure out what is the problem with this method that uses JPQL to validate if an email already exist in the DB, for some reason it does not work. Someone can have a look? Or give another alternative query more simple?

```
@Override
public boolean emailAlreadyExists(String value) {
    Query checkEmailExists = em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(b.email) FROM "
            + Buyer.class.getName() + " b WHERE email = :emailparam");
    checkEmailExists.setParameter("emailparam", value);
    long matchCounter = 0;
    matchCounter = (Long) checkEmailExists.getSingleResult();
    if (matchCounter > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is part of the console output:

> Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-8024] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
>   Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [SELECT COUNT(b.email) FROM entities.Buyer b WHERE b.email = :emailparam], line 1, column 35: syntax error at [.].
>   Internal Exception: MismatchedTokenException(83!=78)

Im sure it has to do something with the syntax. But where i am making the mistake?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically JPA uses short class names (without package name). And I personally have never used aliases in JPA queries, so I am not sure they are supported there. And you do not need them in your query.  And I am not sure the space between = and : is permitted.

So, try this: `SELECT COUNT(email) FROM Buyer WHERE email=:emailparam`

I hope this will work. In this case try to play with the query and see which one of the changes really does the work.

Comment: Tnx for your answer. It is correct, but only one little thing was missing to work, but that is the idea. Here is the working query: SELECT COUNT(b.email) FROM Buyer b WHERE b.email=:emailparam